# Embed python modules in code

Tags: python, boto, psycopg2, python-module

I have a python script that imports two external modules, `psycopg2` and `boto`. But I need to run this script on a lot of machines that don't have those libs installed.

Is there a way to put the code of these libs in the main script, so I can simply copy one file and everything works?

Comment: You should package your project, use eggs with setuptools to define dependencies. You could use fabric to deploy projects on every machines. If you don't want to host your own egg server, you can host your project into a "version control system" such as git and use fabric to pull new release on every machine and lunch the setup script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can package your script by using either [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) or [cx_freeze](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze)